# Java effectively deleting object

Tags: java

I am trying to make a little game in java. I made a class that I call `Game` and some subclasses. I use the subclass `Body` for all kinds of objects in the game. I want a method in `Game` for spawning objects. This method should add a reference to a list so that interactions with other bodies may be calculated later.

The Game class looks something like this:

```
import java.util.*;

class Game {

    public List<Body> bodies = new ArrayList<Body>();

    public void spawn( Body body ) {
        bodies.add( body );
    }
}
```

Right, I think that works. Now I want to be able to deSpawn the bodies as well. I tried this:

```
import java.util.*;

class Game {

    public List<Body> bodies = new ArrayList<Body>();

    public void spawn( Body body ) {
        bodies.add( body );
    }

    public void despawn( Body body ) {
        body = null;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work as expected. I guess it just removes this reference to the object, if that is correct I would have no idea how to remove all references to the object. I guess I could iterate over the array, but that just seems stupid since I have a reference to the actual object. Shouldn't I be able to destroy it? More elegant alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void despawn( Body body ) {
    body = null;
}
```

Here, you are merely setting the value of `body`, passed in as parameter, to `null`.

What you could do is call:

```
public void despawn( Body body ) {
    if(body != null && !bodies.isEmpty()){
        bodies.remove(body);
    }
}
```

Which will remove all occurrences of `body` in the memory, assuming you also dispose of the object passed into the method.

Comment: @SamuelWillems there is still a reference to the object in the list, so it won't ever get cleaned by the GC unless it is removed. Of course, once you pass the `body` parameter in, that object would also have to either fall out of scope or be dereferenced to be cleaned by the GC.

Comment: Yea thanks I get it. Stupid I didn't even know there was a function that worked this way. I am used to keys, this is kind of weird to me. Thanks a lot though!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that `body = null;` is doing is setting `despawn`'s local `body` reference to `null`.  It doesn't affect the actual object.

To remove it from the `bodies` `List`, call the [`remove` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) on `bodies`, passing `body` as an argument.  Make sure that your `Body` class overrides the `equals` method from `Object`, so that the list can properly find the match to remove.

Once `bodies` no longer has a reference, and the `despawn` method completes, and any other references to the object to "despawn" are out of scope or reassigned, then the removed object will be eligible for garbage collection.  It will be destroyed by the garbage collector sometime after nothing references it any more.